# How to prevent multiple users tables from colliding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, collision, multiple-users

I'm creating an application in C# that calls multiple stored procedures. One of the stored procedure creates a table and the others query that table. Multiple users can use the application at the same time. What table would be appropriate in this case to prevent data collision when using the same table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports two different kinds of temporary tables: local and global.

Local `#temporary` tables are only visible to the session that created them.

Global `##temporary` tables are visible to all sessions.

For more information, see the "Temporary Tables" section of the TechNet article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx).